# Xcode 6 Launch Image for iPhone 6 plus

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

Where should I need to put my @3x image in Launch screen section. There is no placeholder for @3x in Launch Image Section.

Even if I put @3x image in my resource. Its not automatically picking it up.
Can anybody tell how can we use @3x image in Xcode 6 for slash.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look I prepeared image for you, because it is easier to understand, than words

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your xcassets file you need to check the attribute inspector of the LaunchScreen section. You should be able to check a checkbox saying "iOS8 and Later" (Portrait and Landscape).

When you did this you should see the placeholder Retina HD 5.5 and Retina HD 4.7.