# Why status bar font size changes on iphone 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-6

I was reported that my application changes the font of the status bar on iphone 6. I tested on the emulator and I was able to recreate this problem as you can see on this video: http://screencast.com/t/KxVmMRC7

The application on the video is just an empty test so this seems to be happening by default. This happens only on iphone 6, never saw it on any other device.

I wonder if anyone is familiar with this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically your app enters to a [scaled](http://www.zdnet.com/apple-to-developers-your-apps-will-scale-on-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-screens-7000033490/) mode when you don't have the app's launch image for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970142/xcode-6-launch-image-for-iphone-6-plus) on how to set the launch images correctly.

Comment: What if I'm not using lauch images at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25821550/1169452 basically you need to have the launch image for it know whether to scale or not. You can in fact specify a LaunchScreen.xib and use size class if you don't want to use launch images but support iPhone 6 and 6 plus with native resolution